# how to register javascript excute first without edit html

Tags: javascript

I have a problem with javascript execute the order.

In HTML code:

```
<script src="1.js"></script>
<script>console.log("2.js");</script>
<script>console.log("3.js");</script>
```

How can I execute **3.js** first without edit HTML code?

Thank you

Comment: Do you mean execute 3.js, first, without changing the loading order around?

Comment: Yes, i only can edit the code in line 3

Comment: you will never execute anything inside 3.js your code will simply print 3.js as text

Comment: Sorry, it is impossible.

Comment: I'm sorry. What i mean how to the code 'console.log("3.js");' execute first when it in  scripttag 3

Answer (score 0):

Maybe from 1.js file

```
   document.getElementsByTagName("script");
```

method returns a collection of an elements with the specified tag name, as a NodeList object.
The nodes can be accessed by index numbers